# How to log requests to stdout in Tornado web server?

Tags: tornado

I'm starting to develop a simple Tornado application, and I'd like to see request log in stdout while I develop. Currently I only see 404 warning messages.

Is there a way to have all requests printed in stdout?

Comment: `print` isn't a good alternative to a proper logging solution

Comment: true. but my need here was not a proper logging solution, I just need print to get visual feedback during development

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add this to your app:

```
import tornado.options
tornado.options.parse_command_line()
```

The parse_command_line function sets up logging. You can then pass `--logging=loglevel` (e.g. debug)

Comment: Is this still valid? I'm getting a `No handlers could be found for logger "tornado.application` error in this way as soon as I'm calling `logging.getLogger()`.

Answer (score 36):

You can add this to you application:

```
from tornado.log import enable_pretty_logging
enable_pretty_logging()
```

By default it writes logs to stdout.

Comment: Thanks man! this is it. Then you can "tail -f /var/log/supervisor/tornado-stdout.log" --- or whatevver

Comment: This seems that it is not true anymore in 2018

Comment: `import tornado.log` and then `tornado.log.enable_pretty_logging()` working with Tornado version 6.1.0.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you `print`? Use `print self.request` somewhere inside the request handler (maybe inside the [prepare](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.prepare) method).

Or better:

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def prepare(self):
        print self.request

class SomeHandler(BaseHandler):
    ...
```

use a base class for your request handlers and subclass it from that time on.

Comment: tornado makes asynchronous io, print is a blocking request IO, you should always use the logger instead

Comment: Alright, but I thought about using this only for debugging purposes.

Comment: i can't use 'print' function, damn tornado